# JS or PHP to determine if my page is accessed from within my domain or not

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a reliable way (other than use of cookies) to determine if a particular link within my site was used to access a page in my site or not?

If no, is there a reliable method to determine if a page on my site was accessed from within my domain or if it was reached from another site?

I would prefer the first method but the second may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to determine the referring URL: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @CraigTucker if my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think so what you are looking for is from where the request for the page has been genereated. Please correct me if i am wrong.

This can be done using request header

`Referer: https://example.com/[path]`

This gives you from where the request originated

Ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer